# BinaryMeta/BinaryData returning null

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery

I am trying to get the binary URL from Broker DB. I tried the below content delivery API. I am getting null value. But binary is published into Broker and it is available when I query the DB. Any thoughts on this?

I tried with fully qualified TCM ID of the binary as well as binary short ID.

```
 //create a new BinaryMetaFactory instance:
            BinaryMetaFactory binaryMetaFactory12 = new BinaryMetaFactory();
            //find the metadata for the specified binary
            BinaryMeta binaryMeta12 = binaryMetaFactory12.GetMeta("tcm:255-14072");
            //print the path to the output stream:
            if (binaryMeta12 != null)
            {

            }
```

other way

```
 Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.BinaryFactory factory = new BinaryFactory(); 
            //BinaryData binaryData = factory.GetBinary("14072".ToString());
            BinaryData binaryData = factory.GetBinary(Convert.ToInt32(255), Convert.ToInt32(14072));
```

Comment: Aren't you specifying the Publication ID and Binary ID parameters in the wrong order to `BinaryFactory.GetBinary`?  You may also have to specify a Variant ID. See, for example: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Statics/BinaryFileManager.cs

Comment: Hi Rick: I was checking the "BinaryData" class instead "BinaryMeta" class. However, I am filtering the binary based on publication id and some other criteria. I want to get the URL of the results. So, I am not able to pass the "variant id" for each binary because it might vary binary to binary and I don't get the details. So, is there any way to get binary URL by using publication id and item id or fully qualified binary tcm id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Binaries have a Variant ID, but you don't know this Variant ID when you request the Binary, you can use `BinaryMetaFactory.GetAllVariantMeta`. It has the following signature:

`BinaryMeta[] GetAllVariantMeta(string binaryUri)`

Note that it may return multiple `BinaryMeta` objects, because you may have multiple Binaries with the same ID but with different Variant IDs (that is the whole purpose of Variant ID).